# Receiving an EOF error when running my bash script

Tags: bash, shell, eof

I have a bash script that is meant to be a simple calendar application.  Whenever I run it, as soon as I give input the script terminates and I receive the message:

"./addtocalendar-jrussial.sh: line 104: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

I'm not sure what is causing this.  All of my brackets, braces, quotes and if-else statements are closed.

This is the code that I have currently:

```
#!/bin/bash

# addagenda--Prompts the user to add a new event for the agenda script

agendafile="$HOME/.agenda"


isDayName()
{
    # Return 0 if all is well, 1 on error.
    case $(echo $1 | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]') in
    sun*|mon*|tue*|wed*|thu*|fri*|sat*) retval=0 ;;
    * ) retval=1 ;;
    esac
    return $retval
}


isMonthName()
{
    case $(echo $1 | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]') in
    jan*|feb*|mar*|apr*|may|jun*) return 0 ;;
    jul*|aug*|sep*|oct*|nov*|dec*) return 0 ;;
    * ) return 1 ;;
    esac
}


normalize()
{
    # Return string with first char uppercase, next two lowercase.
    /bin/echo -n $1 | cut -c1 | tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]'
    echo $1 | cut -c2-3| tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]'
}


if [ ! -w $HOME ] ;
then
    echo "$0: cannot write in your home directory ($HOME)" >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo "Agenda: The Unix Reminder Service"
/bin/echo -n "Date of event (day mon, day month year, or dayname): "
read word1 word2 word3 junk

if isDayName $word1 ;
then
    if [ ! -z "$word2" ] ;
    then
        echo "Bad dayname format: just specify the day name by itself." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    date="$(normalize $word1)"

else
    if [ -z "$word2" ] ;
    then
        echo "Bad dayname format: unknown day name specified" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    if [ ! -z "$(echo $word1|sed 's/[[:digit:]]//g')" ] ; then
        echo "Bad date format: please specify day first, by day number" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    if [ "$word1" -lt 1 -o "$word1" -gt 31 ] ;
    then
        echo "Bad date format: day number can only be in range 1-31" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    if [ ! isMonthName $word2 ] ;
    then
        echo "Bad date format: unknown month name specified." >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    word2="$(normalize $word2)"

    if [ -z "$word3" ] ;
    then
        date="$word1$word2"
    else
        if [ ! -z "$(echo $word3|sed 's/[[:digit:]]//g')" ] ;
        then
            echo "Bad date format: third field should be year." >&2
            exit 1
        elif [ $word3 -lt 2000 -o $word3 -gt 2500 ] ;
        then
            echo "Bad date format: year value should be 2000-2500" >&2
            exit 1
        fi
        date="$word1$word2$word3"
    fi
fi

/bin/echo -n "One-line description: "
read description

# Ready to write to data file

echo "$(echo $date|sed 's/ //g')|$description" >> $agendafile

exit 0
```

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/ will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: And check if you have proper line terminations (`dos2unix`).